# INNER JOIN in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, flatten, google-query-language

I don't know or remember the technical name of what I'm looking for but I think an example will be enough for you to understand exactly what I'm looking for.

Given table **A**

```
a   x1
b   x2
c   x1
```

and Table **B**

```
x1  x
x1  y
x1  z
x2  p
x2  z
```

I Need Table **C**

```
a   x
a   y
a   z
b   p
b   z
c   x
c   y
c   z
```

I'm looking for a formula or a set of them to get table C

*I guess just need to add an extra row on the **C** table with each value of the first column on the table **A** for each corresponding value of **TableA!Column2** to **TableB!Column1** But I can't find how*

I think this is a simple SQL Inner Join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({TRIM(FLATTEN(SPLIT(QUERY(REPT(IF($A2:A="",,$A2:A&"♦"), IFNA(VLOOKUP($B2:$B, QUERY({$D2:$D}, 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"), 2, 0))),,9^9), "♦"))), IFNA(VLOOKUP(
 TRIM(FLATTEN(SPLIT(QUERY(REPT(IF($A2:A="",,$B2:B&"♦"), IFNA(VLOOKUP($B2:$B, QUERY({$D2:$D}, 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"), 2, 0))),,9^9), "♦")))&COUNTIFS(
 TRIM(FLATTEN(SPLIT(QUERY(REPT(IF($A2:A="",,$A2:A&"♦"), IFNA(VLOOKUP($B2:$B, QUERY({$D2:$D}, 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"), 2, 0))),,9^9), "♦"))), 
 TRIM(FLATTEN(SPLIT(QUERY(REPT(IF($A2:A="",,$A2:A&"♦"), IFNA(VLOOKUP($B2:$B, QUERY({$D2:$D}, 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"), 2, 0))),,9^9), "♦"))), ROW(INDIRECT("O1:O"&COUNTA(
 TRIM(FLATTEN(SPLIT(QUERY(REPT(IF($A2:A="",,$B2:B&"♦"), IFNA(VLOOKUP($B2:$B, QUERY({$D2:$D}, 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"), 2, 0))),,9^9), "♦")))))), "<="&ROW(INDIRECT("O1:O"&COUNTA(
 TRIM(FLATTEN(SPLIT(QUERY(REPT(IF($A2:A="",,$B2:B&"♦"), IFNA(VLOOKUP($B2:$B, QUERY({$D2:$D}, 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"), 2, 0))),,9^9), "♦"))))))), 
 {D2:D&COUNTIFS(D2:D, D2:D, ROW(O2:O), "<="&ROW(O2:O)), E2:E}, 2, 0))})
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but I have duplicated data over column2 in table A, I thought this was clear.
And this is not working for duplicates

Comment: Check out the Sheet Problem Definition on this Spreadsheet Sample :)
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vsCO18TAbwaVAAQZLPol1jCE1cPX1n-L2LroK649CSc/edit#gid=192736100

Comment: Wow, it seems to work, but the level of knowledge you have to have for this thing is amazing. I'm just gonna use it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Be sure all ranks have the same size.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is a JOIN in SQL, which duplicates values. Inner, left, right or full defines the behavior when there are no matches on both sides.

The easiest way I can think to do this is by using [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) to make a custom function to use in a formula:

```js
function JOINRANGES(range1, index1, range2, index2) {
 const result = []
 for(let row1 of range1) {
   for (let row2 of range2) {
     if (row1[index1] == row2[index2]) {
       const r = [...row1, ...row2]
       // Remove the keys themselves
       r.splice(row1.length+index2, 1)
       r.splice(index1, 1)
       result.push(r)
     }
   }
 }
 return result
}
```

Then you may use it in a sheets formula on the top-left column:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOINRANGES(A1:B3, 1, D1:E6, 0))
```

The first and the third arguments are the ranges, and the second and the fourth arguments are the index (starting with 0) of the column inside the range.

The final result:

[image: Screenshot of the result]

If you don’t know about Google Apps Script, [the about page in the `google-apps-script` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) has a lot of guides and documentation that is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Las answer won't work with duplicates on TableA!column1.
Instructions Showing the key formulas:

Just add an intermediate column

```
JOIN(",",FILTER(E$2:E,D$2:D=L2))
```

so you can grab the data from them

```
INDEX(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",FILTER(M$2:M,K$2:K=O2)),",")),COUNTIF(O$1:O1,"="&O2)+1)
```

into a multiplied column

```
ArrayFormula(TRIM(FLATTEN(SPLIT(QUERY(REPT(IF(A2:A="",,A2:A&"♦"), IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B, QUERY({D2:D}, "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"), 2, 0))),,9^9), "♦"))))
```

[here is an example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vsCO18TAbwaVAAQZLPol1jCE1cPX1n-L2LroK649CSc/edit#gid=1264319084) and a Picture.
[image]

Comment: After seeing @player0 work I'm sure this can be done more efficiently and compact, but it is as hard as I can give in this matter, and this is a basic topic for QUERYs on Google Spreadsheet, which I have never seen an answer on the web :S